# How to access the site name for all the paths and configure for route

Tags: reactjs, iis

In IIS, application name is reactapp.

Am having my application running in, http://11.11.111.11/reactapp/
I want to configure the path for all the routes in the application, for example:

```
path="/reactapp/"
path="/reactapp/show_users"
path="/reactapp/show_admins"
```

So in the front-end code, I don't want to hardcode my application name.
How can I configure this in my route?

Comment: What do you mean by hard coding your routes? have you checked [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)

Comment: I mean in the above-mentioned code, I had included the application name in the route path. Which I want to replace with the generalized code which will give the application name. So if I deploy in some other name also routes will work without hard-coding it.